# Why doesn't content hide?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a test HTML file in which I toggle the class 'hide' with JavaScript but the content does not hide, I can't understand why, what can be done in order to  get the content to toggle between hide/show.

```js
function init() {
  let button = document.querySelector('#menubutton');
  button.onclick = buttonClicked;
}

function buttonClicked(event) {
  let content = document.querySelector('.content');
  content.classList.toggle('hide');
}

window.addEventListener('load', init);
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.menu {
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  position: absolute;
}

.color {
  background-color: pink;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="title">
      <button id="menubutton">Toggle</button>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <a href="#">Uno</a>
      <a href="#">Dos</a>
      <a href="#">Tres</a>
      <a href="#">Cuatro</a>
      <a href="#">Cinco</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="color"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the `hide` class, the element has two classes, and they both specify different `display` properties. The property from `.content` is taking precedence.

Make your selector more specific so it will take precedence, use `.content.hide`.

```js
function init() {
  let button = document.querySelector('#menubutton');
  button.onclick = buttonClicked;
}

function buttonClicked(event) {
  let content = document.querySelector('.content');
  content.classList.toggle('hide');
}

window.addEventListener('load', init);
```

```css
.content.hide {
  display: none;
}

.menu {
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  position: absolute;
}

.color {
  background-color: pink;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="title">
      <button id="menubutton">Toggle</button>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <a href="#">Uno</a>
      <a href="#">Dos</a>
      <a href="#">Tres</a>
      <a href="#">Cuatro</a>
      <a href="#">Cinco</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="color"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Another possibility is to use `!important` in the `.hide` CSS to make it override other styles.

```js
function init() {
  let button = document.querySelector('#menubutton');
  button.onclick = buttonClicked;
}

function buttonClicked(event) {
  let content = document.querySelector('.content');
  content.classList.toggle('hide');
}

window.addEventListener('load', init);
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none !important;
}

.menu {
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  position: absolute;
}

.color {
  background-color: pink;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="title">
      <button id="menubutton">Toggle</button>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <a href="#">Uno</a>
      <a href="#">Dos</a>
      <a href="#">Tres</a>
      <a href="#">Cuatro</a>
      <a href="#">Cinco</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="color"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do toggle, the classes are being toggled this way:

```
"content"
```

and

```
"content hide"
```

Now, both `content` and `hide` set `display` property. When there's such conflict, the rule that is defined later (either within `<style>` or in a further stylesheet) takes precedence.

You could see [@Barmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70299497/3001736) which shows `!important` and `.content.hide` to force higher precedence.

Or you could just define `.hide` after `.content` which gives it higher precedence.

```js
function init() {
  let button = document.querySelector('#menubutton');
  button.onclick = buttonClicked;
}

function buttonClicked(event) {
  let content = document.querySelector('.content');
  content.classList.toggle('hide');
}

window.addEventListener('load', init);
```

```css
.menu {
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  position: absolute;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.color {
  background-color: pink;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="title">
      <button id="menubutton">Toggle</button>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <a href="#">Uno</a>
      <a href="#">Dos</a>
      <a href="#">Tres</a>
      <a href="#">Cuatro</a>
      <a href="#">Cinco</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="color"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Nice answer too! It's good to have other/more perspectives, thanks.